# Apache NiFi: How to update an attribute of flowfile with a Http response from API?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to report to an API with some information with attributes of each flowfile. Sometimes the API return some important information in JSON. My goal is update the attributes of the original flowfile with the new data that return the API.

My sketch-strategy to update the FlowFile -> *AttributeToJSON* (But the entire content of the FlowFile is replaced by the JSON, **1°problem**) -> *HttpInvoke* to send the information to the API -> The API return a JSON with some data -> Extract some data from the JSON with some Process and update the attributes of the Flowfile

**1° problem**: I can separate the flowfile, the original and another (to modify it with *AttributeToJSON*). But how can I merge them in the future? Which process I need to combine the original flowfile and the "new" attributes that I build with the response of the API?

Perhaps I can save the orginal file in a directory with *PutFile*, and by another way process the info, and some point use the *FetchFile* (with attributes know where is save the file), and then take the data and Attributes together.

**extra** Can I send with *HttpInvoke* POST Request with only the attributes(one of them written in JSON)?.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the *lookup* processors -- [`LookupAttribute`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupAttribute/index.html) and [`LookupRecord`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupRecord/index.html). These processors allow you to enrich the existing flowfile with additional information.

It looks like right now, the [`RestLookupService`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-services-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.lookup.RestLookupService/index.html) is available for record enrichment but not attribute enrichment. You may want to file a Jira requesting this, and in the meantime you can use [`SimpleScriptedLookupService`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.lookup.script.SimpleScriptedLookupService/index.html) to make an HTTP invocation from that processor.

Comment: Thank you @Andy. I will research about these process. Where can I find some examples of these processes?